# How to change the name of a file in C?

Tags: c, string, filenames

Currently, I am taking some measurements and saving the data in a txt file. My C program is supposed to run without interruptions and it writes several files, one after the other. On another machine I want to have a routine to copy the files that are done writing and are ready to be analysed. To distinguish between them, I want the files to be written with a tag, something like: `*.part.txt`.

I was thinking of using the `rename()` function. My problem is, I do not know how to easily change the string from `*.part.txt` to just `*.txt`.

This would be much easier using Python, but I have to use C for this one and sadly, I lack the necessary experience to solve this by myself.

Comment: So, is your question really about changing the name(s) of multiple files with the constraints that they fall within the wildcard description?  Or, do you want to remove the `.part` section of the original filename?

Comment: Make a copy of the longer name; find the start of `.part.txt` ([`strstr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strstr.html)); overwrite it with the new, shorter string `.txt`; use the copy of the file name in the `rename()` command. It isn't hard; it's only modestly fiddly. Using [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html) is a good idea if it is available (it's a POSIX function). If not: `char *strdup(const char *src) { size_t len = strlen(src) + 1; char *dst = malloc(len); if (dst != 0) memmove(dst, src, len); return dst; }`.

Comment: Can you use Boost libraries?

Comment: The program should change the name as soon as it is done writing the file. It should only remove the `.part` section of the filename. I will give Jonathan Leffler's suggestion a try. Thank you for your answers.